# Programmatically change headphone's button behavior

Tags: c#, registry, hardware, headphones

Is it possible to programmatically change the process that starts once the user click the [LifeChat LX-3000](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/p/lifechat-lx-3000/JUG-00001) center button?

I don't have any kind of experience programming with hardware so don't know if it's even possible. The problem is, a client of us has a lot of this headphones and we want to be able to change the default behavior of that button from open live messenger to open our CRM. I try to follow [this instructions](http://www.techpowerup.com/forums/showthread.php?t=150345) to modify the registry as doing (not programmatically):

- Find HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{F5F545A6-39C4-40B5-814D-B45040A89FB5}\LocalServer32
- Remove the (Default) value by double clicking it and deleting the text
- Change the value to *OurCRMExePath*

But this doesn't work. I suppose things changed since the date that web page was wrote. Any idea? I suppose first step would be to know which registry entry does that button modify and then go and change it. But, how can one get to know that?